# Derivative in function form

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I have a function in mathematica defined as

```
 b[n_, x_] := x^n/n!/\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = n\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\*FractionBox[\(x^k\), \(k!\)]\)
```

which is the same as
$$b(n,x)=\frac{\frac{x^n}{n!}}{e^x-1-x-...-\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}}$$

I want to take the derivative of this differential expression with respect to $x$:

$$x^2b''(n,x)+\left[3x^2+(1-3n)x\right]b'(n,x)+\left[2x^2+(1-4n)x+2n^2\right]b(n,x)$$

So i write this into mathematica:

```
 a[n_, x_] := x^2*D[D[b[n, x], x], x] + (3 x^2 + (1 - 3 n) x)*D[b[n, x], x] + (2 x^2 + (1 - 4 n) x + 2 n^2)*b[n, x]

 D[a[n, x], x]
```

from here, mathematica spits out the answer, but it gives the answer in terms of

```
 (1 - 3 n + 6 x) (-((E^(-2 x) x^(-1 + 2 n) Gamma[n])/( n! (Gamma[n] - Gamma[n, x])^2)) + (E^-x n x^(-1 + n) Gamma[n])/(
n! (Gamma[n] - Gamma[n, x])) - (E^-x x^n Gamma[n])/(n! (Gamma[n] - Gamma[n, x]))) + ...
```

I am hoping someone can help get the output to be in terms of a derivative instead of the gamma function factorization that is being generated when I take the derivative of $a(n,x)$.  For example, the first few terms of the derivative are
$$x^2b'''(n,x)+2xb''(n,x)+\left[3x^2+(1-3n)x\right]b''(n,x)+\left[6x+(1-3n)\right]b'(n,x)+...$$

Is there a way mathematica can do this as an output instead of the long string of factors comprised of the gamma function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the definition of `b` is being substituted (and some of the factorials are being converted to `Gamma`).  You need to keep `b` from being evaluated.  Without knowing how you wish to use the result, here is a possibility:

```
a[n_, x_] := 
 Inactivate[
  x^2*D[D[b[n, x], x], x] + (3 x^2 + (1 - 3 n) x) * D[b[n, x], x] +
    (2 x^2 + (1 - 4 n) x + 2 n^2)*b[n, x],
  b]

D[a[n, x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you don't like the derivatives of `b` being displayed as partial derivative, well, it's because you've declared `b` to the a function of two variable.  *Mathematica* is just displaying which variable is being differentiated.

Here's a more roundabout way, but keeping your definition of `a` and avoid the V10 `Inactive`, which could have been used here instead of `HoldForm`:

```
a[n_, x_] := 
 x^2*D[D[b[n, x], x], x] + (3 x^2 + (1 - 3 n) x) * D[b[n, x], x] +
    (2 x^2 + (1 - 4 n) x + 2 n^2)*b[n, x]    

Hold[D[a[n, x], x]] /. DownValues[a] /. b -> HoldForm[b] // ReleaseHold
```

Comment: Your first result with the inactivate function is PERFECT!!!  That is exactly what I am looking for...

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extended comment.

If you use (Full)Simplify there is no long string of terms even with b[n,x] being evaluated.

```
Clear[a, b]

b[n_, x_] = (x^n/n!)/Sum[x^k/k!, {k, n, Infinity}] //
  FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
Limit[x^2 D[b[n, x], {x, 2}] +
  (3 x^2 + (1 - 3 n) x) D[b[n, x], x] +
  (2 x^2 + (1 - 4 n) x + 2 n^2) b[n, x], x -> 0]
```

> 2*n^2

```
a[n_, x_] = Piecewise[{
   {2 n^2, x == 0}},
  x^2 D[b[n, x], {x, 2}] +
    (3 x^2 + (1 - 3 n) x) D[b[n, x], x] +
    (2 x^2 + (1 - 4 n) x + 2 n^2) b[n, x] //
   Simplify]
```

[image]

```
D[a[n, x], x] // FullSimplify
```

[image]